# Download data from a table on webpage with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, asp.net, firefox, automation, firebug

Hi all I want to download the tables from 
http://www.bseindia.com/members/DirectoryOtherIntermediaries.aspx?expandable=2 
To navigate to next page a java script gets run:
eg: javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grvMember','Page$2') is run when we click on 2nd page button.
I want to download tables from all such pages.
I dont know how to download it from firebug. IS there any other method currently i am searching about firebug options but not able to figure out.

ps: on the web page select intermediatery as sub-broker option, give name of sub broker as 'a'.Then say submit, a table gets generated.

Comment: Have you used Copy/Paste ? Actually What you are up to is not clear.

Comment: actually i want to download all the information on all pages, so manually copy pasting is not possilbe. the pages are dynamically generated.

Answer (score 0):

For things like this I use the Scratchpad (Shift+F4) in Firefox.

```
var page = 1;
setInterval(function(){
    //copy data here
    page ++;
    __doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grvMember','Page$' + page);
}, 2000);
```

Timers used to not work in Scratchpad but they do now, which is great. If you want to be really fancy, you might be able to hook into when the page is ready.

Comment: when the javascript gets executed the complete page gets reloaded and the script is not getting executed multiple times

Comment: The page you gave actually reloads the entire page when __doPostBack is called. The URL is the same because it submits it through POST, not GET, and sends the parameters in the HTTP headers (GET sends them in the URL). Since the pagination is not Ajax like as I thought, this method won't work. It's probably easier if you just downloaded the pages yourself with the proper POST parameters (find them by analyzing the request/responses in Firebug) and then parsed them. Or, automate Internet Explorer and use its DOM. AutoIt makes IE COM automation very simple.